# Java JDatePicker Display Date to Field

Tags: java, user-interface, debugging, jdatechooser

I have a JDatePicker element in my GUI and it is being created by an external class function called datePicker.java which returns the JDatePickerImpl object.

```
JDatePickerImpl inptDate = new datePicker().date;
```

This works fine and I can enter a date and retrieve it using

```
date = inptDate.getJFormattedTextField().getText();
```

I am wondering if there is a possible way to set the date in a similar way. I tried to use

```
inptDate.getJFormattedTextField().setText(dateValue);
```

Which seemed to work except there are a whole bunch of errors in the background